# how can i ignore division error and zeros while am carrying out an average function

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

am trying to carryout an average calculation on cells in excel but the average comes out well thus the only issue is that it gives an error when the cells are blank yet i want it to show nothing if they are blank. I want also the function to ignore blank cells

```
=ROUND(IF(AVERAGE(N2,X2,AH2,AR2,BB2,BL2,BV2,CF2,CP2,CZ2,DJ2,DT2,ED2,EN2,FH2)="","",--(AVERAGE(N2,X2,AH2,AR2,BB2,BL2,BV2,CF2,CP2,CZ2,DJ2,DT2,ED2,EN2,FH2))),2)
```

Comment: If there is a **blank** it will always return a **blank** since your **first argument** is to check a **blank** and it will not return the **Average value**, to ignore blanks, you may use a formula like this `=SUM(N2,X2,AH2,AR2,BB2,BL2,BV2,CF2,CP2,CZ2,DJ2,DT2,ED2,EN2,FH2)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((N2,X2,AH2,AR2,BB2,BL2,BV2,CF2,CP2,CZ2,DJ2,DT2,ED2,EN2,FH2),0),2)`

Comment: it gives me the average which is fine but i don't want to view the #div!0 error when the cells are blank

Comment: To avoid errors you can wrap your formula within an `IFERROR()` function.